# Вложенный тернарный оператор

Tags: java, тернарный-оператор

Прохожу тест-задачу:

> С помощью тернарного оператора замените инициализацию переменной `b` в указанном коде:

```
int a = 10;
    int b;
    if (a > 0) {
        if (a < 100) {
            b = 1;
        } else {
            b = 0;
        }
    } else {
        b = -1;
    }
```

По-моему, тут надо использовать вложеный тернарный оператор, 
я сделал так:

```
int a = 10;
    int b;
    b = (a > 0) ? ((a < 100) ? b = 1 : b = 0) : b = -1  ;
```

но тест отвечает, что я не прав. Где я ошибаюсь и почему это так?

Comment: А каков собственно вопрос?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, Вы пишете `b = ...? b=1 : b=2`, а надо `b=...? 1 : 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, вложенная тернарная операция. Логически сделал верно. Но допущена синтаксическая ошибка - попытка присвоить значение переменной b внутри тернарной операции.

Правильно должно быть так:

```
int a = 10;
int b = a > 0 ? a < 100 ? 1 : 0 : -1;
```

Вложенное выражение `a < 100 ? 1 : 0` возвращает значение, которое используется в выражении выше `a > 0 ? ВЛОЖЕННОЕ : -1`, которое так же возвращает значение, но уже непосредственно в переменную `b`.

Comment: сделал как ты сказал но тест не пропускает http://joxi.ru/8AnbXnaHjaJJRA
http://joxi.ru/MAjB0adU4JQQNA

Answer (score 0):

точку с запятой нужно убрать, тогда тренажёр съедает задание :) (тоже самое сейчас прохожу)

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Дело не в точке с запятой, а в ошибке компиляции из-за оператора присваивания внутри тернарного оператора